# Tkinter Refresh/Update my frame function?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, refresh, frame, auto-update

I have this window in my program, that read a input from another file and change the color of my objects, but if i change the data in the file, my objects color don't change. How can i create a Button that refresh this to reload my fuction and objects color, or better, automate that.

Ps.: i'm using python 3.7

```
    frametabela = tk.Frame(frame2, width=800, height=300, bg="#c3c3c3")
    frametabela.place(relx=.46, rely=.7, anchor="c")


    if DBA.sdv_xx_01() == 0:
        sdv01_color = BarCor['green']
    elif DBA.sdv_xx_01() == 1:
        sdv01_color = BarCor['yellow']
    else:
        sdv01_color = BarCor['red']


    sdv_xx_01 = tk.Button(frametabela, text="SDV-XX-01", width=18, height=2, bg=sdv01_color, disabledforeground="#000000", state="disabled", font=FONT_STYLE_BUTTONS)

    sdv_xx_01.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Comment: You've posted way too much code. If the problem is with changing the color of a widget, we don't need dozens of widgets. Please consider making a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks, i made it. How is it now?